# Installation on 3 HD setup: mdadm is missing

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid, mdadm

I have an SSD (sda) and 2 HDs (sdb,sdc).
My target is to install Ubuntu on the SSD and setup a RAID0 over the 2 HD. I manually installed `mdadm` and created the `md0` device and created also the partitions I need:

```
swap
/tmp
/var
/home
```

I formatted everything in those 4 partitions and then started the installation.

Everything went OK but then I realized that the system installed in `sda1` (the partition containing `/`) is lacking the `mdadm` tool and the `/etc/mdadm` directory.

Now what?
I can manually add the `linear.ko` module into `/etc/modules`.

But then do I still need to I install `mdadm` and possibly configure it to recognize my partitions under md0 at the boot. How to I do that?

I am now in the installation environment. The system wouldn't properly (re)boot as the devices for above mount-points are not available at boot time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky, but doable.

1. Start a live CD
2. Install madam
3. Manually do the [RAID configuration](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup)
4. Do installation over mdX devices
5. Before rebooting you need to chroot on /target and install mdadm.
6. Reboot and enjoy.

The hard part is step no.5. You can try [this page](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/) for some directions.

Comment: The simple "chroot and install mdadm" is not simple at all. But, yes, it's doable.